# Convert json to python list

Tags: python, json

I'm new to JSON and trying to save the results of the following json response into lists, in order to make some stats.Specifically, i'd like to save the 'results'.

```
{u'draws':
 {u'draw':
 [{u'drawTime': u'22-02-2016T09:00:00', u'drawNo': 542977, u'results': [72, 47, 10, 48, 65, 54, 55, 12, 73, 1, 2, 26, 13, 5, 46, 30, 62, 19, 66, 14]},
 {u'drawTime': u'22-02-2016T09:05:00', u'drawNo': 542978, u'results': [71, 24, 4, 72, 14, 7, 63, 70, 3, 10, 42, 22, 15, 19, 79, 47, 1, 43, 55, 77]},   {u'drawTime': u'22-02-2016T09:10:00', u'drawNo': 542979, u'results': [24, 80, 45, 73, 72, 1, 41, 23, 56, 59, 31, 55, 29, 49, 51, 63, 40, 9, 21, 79]}
```

and it continues like that. Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen the [JSON API](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html)?

Comment: You already have them loaded as python objects (dictionaries), otherwise you wouldn't see the `u` string prefix. Do you just want `mylist = result[u'draws'][u'draw']`?

Comment: yeap, plus some examples but i'm confused. it's my first assignment in that topic.

Comment: There are lots of examples in the documentation for JSON API. Read on.

Comment: Please stop recommending JSON documentation to the OP. The data here is a Python dict, not JSON; the translation from JSON has already been done.

Answer (score 0):

Python has nice modules to parse JSON. Take a look here for quick examples: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/json/

I'm not really sure what you want to do from your question though. What you show in your snippet *is* a Python data structure already... so you could just access the list in question directly, e.g.:

```
results_list = your_data['draws']['draw'][0]['results']
```

and/or make a copy of it if you need:

```
new_list = old_list[:]
```

If you get JSON from somewhere as a string, you can just parse it and do the same:

```
import json
your_data = json.loads(json_string)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've used the json.loads command, i didn't know that after that the structure was considered a python dict and not json.